# Method is_displayed() gets an error before returning an output in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Selenium in Python.

In my script, I wrote this line to check if a particular element exists:

```
doesElementExist = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.MediaThumbnail.Media--playButton>img').is_displayed()
print(doesElementExist)
```

For testing, I ran the script with a website in which I know this element do not exist. Therefore, I'm expecting a False as the returning output since the is_displayed() method returns a boolean.

However, I got an error saying this element do not exist, which stops the script from running instead of returning a false and keep the script going.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~/Desktop/ImageScraping/birdsScrapeTest.py:70 in <module>
    if driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.MediaThumbnail.Media--playButton>img').is_displayed() == True:

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:1251 in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:430 in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:247 in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.MediaThumbnail.Media--playButton>img"}
```

Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the `is_displayed()` method does. This method will tell you whether the `element` is visible or not visible (hidden but in the DOM). So   in order to implement the usage that  you are expecting you could do instead:

```py
try:
    doesElementExist = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.MediaThumbnail.Media--playButton>img').is_displayed()
except NoSuchElementException:
    doesElementExists = False
    print("Element doesn't exists")

print(doesElementExist)
```

This logic should work whether the element is not present on the page or just hidden

Comment: Tried and got this error:NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Comment: You need to import the NoSuchElementException first like,  from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

Comment: ok now it works!